# When using f.read() the iteration loops per letter

Tags: python, for-loop, text

I am iterating through my text file, but when I use the read() function, the loop iterates through the letters instead of the sentences.

with the following code:

```
for question in questions: # voor elke question moet er door alle lines geiterate worden
    print(f"Question: {question}")
    f = open("glad.txt", "r")
    text = f.read()
      # text = text.replace("\n", ". ")
      # text = text.replace(". .", "")
      # text = text.replace(".. ", ". ")
      # text = text.replace(".", ".\n")

      #text = text.strip(".. ")
      # test = text.replace('[bewerken | brontekst bewerken]', "")   
      # output = re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', test)
    for line in text:
      text = str(line) #het antwoord moet een string zijn
      #encoding met tokenizen van de zinnen
      print(text)
```

The output is:
[image]

But when I remove the f.read()

I receive the expected out:
[image]

I need to use the read() function, otherwise I cannot use the replace() function. Does anyone how to solve this issue?

Comment: I would recommend using 'with statement' structure when working with files, it is definitely a better practice: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `text = f.read()`, you are getting the whole text file into `text`. When you iterate over a string in Python, it gives you one character per iteration.

Since you want to continue using `.read()`, use `splitlines()`:

```
text = f.read().splitlines()
```

Now, `text` is a list which you can freely iterate the same way you are already doing:

```
for line in text:
```

Answer (score 7):

`f.read()` converts the text file into a string. So if you iterate through a string, it will loop every character:

```
>>> for i in 'Hello World':
    print(i)

    
H
e
l
l
o
 
W
o
r
l
d
>>>
```

Whereas without `.read()`, just `f`, would iterate line by line through the text file, it would be a sequence of strings (each line), it would be something like:

```
>>> for i in ['Hello', 'World']:
    print(i)

    
Hello
World
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers described the problem. However, the standard way to do this in python according to the best practices would be the following:

```
with open("glad.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        # do the stuff
```